# Web Development - SQL Creating a Recent Pages

Tags: mysql, sql, database, go, web

I'm creating a web application where one of the features will include getting the recent games played. I want to make it so the 25 most recent games played will be on the first page, with a page selection at the bottom. (Games data will be grabbed from MYSQL)

I understand this is a concept many sites already have, but after extensive googling I'm uncertain of a way to efficiently do this. The only thing I can currently think of is querying every game of theirs then splitting it into pages, but wouldn't that become extremely inefficient when it gets in the thousands?

Any help, or link to outside sources that explain this topic would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Typically this issue would be solved with proper schema definitions.  I would imagine a query like "SELECT * FROM games WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY date_played DESC LIMIT {page_number - 1 * 25}, 25"

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

For pagination use [`limit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement.
>
> ... the first argument specifies the [zero origin] offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. ...
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

So for the first page it's enough to request all games played, order by time_played DESCending, limit 25. Just be sure to put an index on the time_played column.

Comment: I see, this makes perfect sense! My only question is if I'm creating a page selection at the footer of the page, similar to other sites, (where it has the 4 next page numbers, and then the last page number), how will I know what the last page number will be? I understand I can get some sort of number of  rows in the db and then divide it by how many I will be showing on each page, but where do I get that number? The table the games are stored in aren't just for that user, so I couldn't do something like get the last row in the table and see it's time_played id.

Comment: `select count(*) from tbl where player='bob';`

Comment: Yes but that's what I'm trying to avoid, else why wouldn't I just select all in the first place? I'm worried about the speed if I select all, hence for this post.

Comment: First, if you're worried about speed, bench it both ways, and then decide if the time difference matters. (Though beware of caching effects.) Second, you *do* have an index on `player`, yes? Look at the `EXPLAIN` plan produced by the backend optimizer. Often a count(*) query can be answered with many fewer I/Os than one that transfers lots of row data. Also, consider limiting to time range of 24 or 6 months, and use compound index on (player, play_time). In the end, your site's usage statistics are certain to have a big effect on performance of one or another query.

Comment: If your benchmark results show that `count(*)` introduces unacceptably long response times, then just run a daily cron job to compute summary statistics and store them in another table. Then the "online" query can combine a count from the summary table with a date range limited `count(*)` query.

Comment: So let me understand this correctly. I should: on page load - query for ALL appropriate rows to get total page numbers, then on page switches limit the query to just 15 - 25? If so, how long would you reckon it'd take to query a table with ~50,000 entries?

Comment: You didn't show us `show create table tbl \G` (nor even reveal the name of `tbl`) so we can't see your indexes. You haven't shown us the `EXPLAIN` plans of two competing queries yet. Suppose Bob played 50k games. The prediction I offered above is that elapsed time for `select count(*) from tbl where player='bob'` will be much much shorter than elapsed time to transfer 50k rows with `select * from tbl where player='bob'`. Post the benchmark results in an Answer and tell us the time difference. Create offline daily summaries if the online benchmarking reveals unacceptably high latencies.